# flutter multi isolates support for packages

Tags: flutter, dart

why are packages like cached_network_image using the main isolate for every thing like downloading and storing?

do we need to make changes for every package to make it available for multi isolates?

are they affecting the performance?

for every image to be shown in my widget, the package needs to download about 3 MB and store it,and for 10 images we have 30 MB. should that affect the rendering?